# Multisite 404 for pages in includes subdirectory

Tags: multisite

I have recently installed WordPress Multisite on my local dev environment.

The original website, mysite.co.uk, however no longer displays any pages which were in the /includes folder.

Anything in the normal pages directory works fine.  It is just pages from the /includes subdirectory which have suddenly stopped working.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

My htaccess file contains the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

My wp-config file contains the following:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'local.mysite.co.uk');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Thanks
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the change to permalinks.

When I changed it to /%category%/%postname%/, it worked.

Comment: When you get a chance, please accept your answer as the correct one. This may help others having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that 1 of 2 things is happening

1. your .htaccess file might be misconfigured
2. your wpconfig file does not have the proper settings

For information on site configurations needed for mutlisite, check out this page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration

Comment: Thanks for your response - I have added my htaccess and wp-config details.  I have read through that documentation and cannot see anything that I am not doing - I have tried the other htaccess blocks that it suggests for different versions of WP, but does not resolve my issue.